# generic class by protocol in swift

Tags: swift, generics

how I can create a generic class for a protocol like `ModelProto`, I try this way but it doesn't work

```
protocol ItemProto {
}

protocol ModelProto {
    var list: [ItemProto]? { get }
}

class Model<I: ItemProto>: ModelProto { // <-- ERROR !!!
    // Type 'Model<I>' does not conform to protocol 'ModelProto'
    // Do you want to add protocol stubs?
    // var list: [ItemProto]?
    var list: [I]? = nil // whay this line not conform? and how fix it?
}
```

i can do something like this

```
    var list: [ItemProto]? {
        get { return __list__ }
    }
    private var __list__: [I]?
```

but i think it is a bad way. any help?

protocol `ModelProto` mast be **NOT** generic

`class Model<I>` must have to possible use `<I>` class methods for build new items as `<I>`

Comment: obviously, that way I can use different items

Comment: for each model, I must set a specific class for item.

Comment: because item use Mappable protocol from ObjectMapper for build new object by mapper

Comment: in other words, I must have to possible use class methods

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a generic structure for Model:

```
protocol ItemProto { }

protocol ModelProto {
    var list: [ItemProto]? { get }
}

class Model {
    var list: [ItemProto]? = nil
}
```

You'll be able to store any object that conforms to ItemProto.

Answer (score 0):

We you define a generic class with keyword I it means that I is `SomeClass` that confirms the `ItemProto` protocol but in the `ModelProto` you defined `list` as `ItemProto` not the `I` classType so compiler won't compile that.
You need to define a type in the `ModelProto` and use that against the `ItemProto` directly:

```
protocol ModelProto {
    associatedtype ItemType: ItemProto
    var list: [ItemType]? { get }
}
```

Now you tell the compile that I got a `Type` that it confirms `ItemProto`so your `ModelProto` is now a generic protocol.